# How to demonstrate or qualitatively test a Java class before packaging?

Tags: java, testing

My current project contains an interface and an implementation of a RandomTextGenerator type (such as might be used in an adventure game to generate original character or place names).  I am using Maven to compile and package the project and JUnit 5 for unit testing.  I'd like to structure this project properly in order to open-source it (if only just to learn the proper setup).

My JUnit tests do a lot, but they can't *qualitatively* test the big question: do the randomly-generated names come out sounding good?

How should I test this?  Options I'm considering:

- Add a new class with a static void main() that generates and prints a bunch of these names to System.out.
- Add a JUnit test that does the above and then ends with assertTrue(true).
- Build a new project *outside* of this package, which imports the package and does the above.

I'd like to know what's the generally-accepted best practice, given my intent to open-source this project.  Would consumers of my package want to see these tests, or not, and where?

Comment: Generally speaking, I would forego using JUnit for this, since it's not actually a unit test. I would create a class ```SampleGenerator``` that would create some sample output to look through.

Comment: Basically you need a test only if you can automatically evaluate its results. if you need manual steps (like look through list of generate character sequences) then its better to create a class which provides some samples of generated sequences as suggested by @MichaelBianconi